# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (ptnum > 3) in unknown function, file (Java + opencv 2.4.6)

Tags: java, opencv

I'm working on eclipse + opencv 2.4.6 + java api.

Now i have this compilation error :

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (ptnum > 3) in unknown function, file ..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\contours.cpp, line 1969 Exception in thread "main" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: ..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\contours.cpp:1969: error: (-215) ptnum > 3 ]

at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.convexityDefects_0(Native Method)
at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.convexityDefects(Imgproc.java:3170)
```

The partial code is:

```
     List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
     Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
     Imgproc.findContours(imgframe,contours , hierarchy,Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,new Point(0,0));

                for(int i=0;i<contours.size();i++) {

                Imgproc.drawContours(imgframe, contours,i,new Scalar(255,0,255),2,8,hierarchy,0,new Point());
                MatOfInt hull_=new MatOfInt();

                MatOfInt4 convexityDefects=new MatOfInt4();
                Imgproc.convexHull(contours.get(0), hull_);
                Imgproc.convexityDefects(contours.get(0), hull_, convexityDefects);

                }
```

Can you help me??
Thank's

Comment: It's just a guess but I think the problem lies in the number of points in your convex hull. It should have at least 3 points to make using the `convexityDefect` possible. It should be easy enough to check...

Comment: Mahmm00d wow! Resolved, just check if hull_.width()>=3! Thank you so much!:)

Comment: Glad I could be of help :). I think I'd better post it as an answer (for future references).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in the number of points in your convex hull. It should have at least 3 points to make using the `convexityDefect()` possible. It can easily be checked using an `if` in the `for` loop:

```
if(hull_.rows() >= 3){
    Imgproc.convexityDefects(contours.get(0), hull_, convexityDefects);
}
```

Comment: I've posted a wrong code: this is right 'hull_.size().height>=4'

Comment: I thinks `.rows()` would do the job. Also, are you sure it won't work with just 3 points? I can't test it right now.